# Is this a safe method to stop direct file access?

Tags: php, include

```
<?php if(basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]) == basename(__FILE__)) { header ("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");   exit; } ?>
```

I'm putting this into all my PHP files, is it a safe method or can it be bypassed?

Comment: can't you just put them outside of the root directory of your web server?

Answer (score 0):

You should put your core files outside of your website's root.

For example, if your public files are at: `/var/www/site0/public_html`, then put all your core files under the `/var/www/site0/` directory.

Another method is to use constants. Very likely you have a bootstrap script, which includes all of your files (that's why you need direct access protection).

Define a constant at top of your bootstrap script: `define('BOOTSTRAPPED', 1)`,

then put this line at the top of your scripts where you want to prevent direct access: `if (!defined('BOOTSTRAPPED')) exit;`